# Back button not working in Native Activity

Tags: android-ndk

I have a native activity it works fine but when I hit the back button it stalls for a sec then I see...

> I/InputDispatcher(  278): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{411eb580 token=Token{40edc588 ActivityRecord{41180268 u0 com.gleason.native/android.app.NativeActivity}}}.  It has been 5003.6ms since event, 5000.7ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.

...

> E/ActivityManager(  278): ANR in com.gleason.native (com.gleason.native/android.app.NativeActivity)
>   E/ActivityManager(  278): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

I have an example of my code [here](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/6089568)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this fixed it....

```
while (1) {
    int ident;
    int events;
    struct android_poll_source* source;
    while ((ident=ALooper_pollAll(-1, NULL, &events,
                (void**)&source)) >= 0) {
      if (source != NULL) {
        source->process(state, source);
      }
      if (state->destroyRequested != 0) {
        term_display();
        return;
      }
    }
}
```